# Porting: how can i convert those coffeescript into lua?

Tags: lua, coffeescript

```
((contextObject) ->
          return (contextObject.isInherent or contextObject.isAdditionalInherent) and !contextObject.isHiddenToUI and !@getGameSession().getModifierClassForType(contextObject.type).isHiddenToUI
        ).bind(@)
```

```
  isNotOwnedByPlayer: @::isOwnedByGameSession
```

hi guys, i'm trying to port some coffeescript codes into lua, and i have no ideas what those coffeescript menas,

any idea for how can i convert it as lua?

looked some coffeescript doc

Comment: There's not enough context from that bit of code to say. There has to be something to the left of your first function. And it's returning a boolean based on the value of lots of other properties.

The coffee script specific stuff here is that `@` means `this`, and `::` accesses the prototype / class.

Is there a library used here?

Comment: hi caffeinated! the full snipet of first function is:

Comment: filteredContextObjects = _.filter(@modifiersContextObjects, ((contextObject) ->
          return (contextObject.isInherent or contextObject.isAdditionalInherent) and !contextObject.isHiddenToUI and !@getGameSession().getModifierClassForType(contextObject.type).isHiddenToUI
        ).bind(@))